# How to set Singleton userControl visibility to true or false in C# windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, singleton

I have implemented a **Singleton** `userControl` in order to interact with another classes during the application is running. It works well in background but I want to show (set visibility = true) designed `userControl` when clicking on a `button`! When Application is running and I click the `button` it shows nothing in the designed form. here is the code that I set the visibility to true in `Form.cs` file:

```
private void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     panelYellow.Height = buttonSearch.Height;
     panelYellow.Top = buttonSearch.Top;
     searchPanel.getInstance().Visible = true;
}
```

And here is part of my singleton `userControl` class definition:

```
public partial class searchPanel : UserControl
{
     private searchPanel()
     {
         InitializeComponent();

     }

     private static searchPanel sp = null;

     public static searchPanel getInstance()
     {
         if (sp == null)
         {
             sp = new searchPanel();
         }
         return sp;
     }
}
```

Comment: You must add your searchPanel to form as a control.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I didn't touch winforms, but from what I can remember you cannot really put a private constructor for a UserControl / form.
But another thing that could work is that you can try adding it dynamically in its parent form by setting it with **Parent** property. Because from what I see, if you didn't put it in the designer, it will never show up.

Anyway the question would be:
- Why do you want to use a singleton for a userControl ?

Answer (score 0):

You must add your searchPanel to form as a control.

```
private void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     panelYellow.Height = buttonSearch.Height;
     panelYellow.Top = buttonSearch.Top;
     searchPanel.getInstance().Visible = true;
     this.Controls.Add(searchPanel.getInstance()); // add this line
}
```

Also your implementation of Singleton is not wrong but can be improved.

```
public searchPanel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // write your Singleton code here
}
```

Comment: I added your recommended line but it is not working yet.

Comment: Your user control may be under another control. Set your user control's left and top properties to a different value.